# Issue with Rosewell network adapter

Tags: installation, 13.04, bash, permissions, sudo

When running the install.sh script for my roswell network adapter RnX-N180UBE I get an error

```
Cannot change ownership to uid 1007, gid 501: Operation not permitted
```

If anyone has any experience with this, I would greatly appreciate the help, it's my first day working with ubuntu

Full script: http://pastebin.com/jQ0uVgjE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please drag and drop the file from the pendrive to your desktop. Then, in the terminal:

```
cd Desktop
```

And the remaining steps as before.

Comment: Well that did seem to fix the Operation Not Permitted problem, but it still gives me errors in the end, but that might just be a problem with the script... [link](http://pastebin.com/gcW0LqTG)

Comment: I think the file you are trying to compile is too old for your 3.8.0-xx kernel version. Likely, the driver you are trying to compile already exists in Ubuntu 13.04 and just needs some troubleshooting. That should be the subject of a new question, I'd think.